# Is $\operatorname{D}_+(T_0)$ dense in $\operatorname{Proj}k[T_0,\cdots T_n]/I$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show the proposition

> Every affine $k$-scheme $X$ of finite type is isomorphic to some dense open subscheme of a projective $k$-scheme $\overline{X}$ of finite type.

(Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}k[T_1, \cdots T_n]/I$ for some ideal $I = (f_1, \cdots f_m)$ of $k[T_1, \cdots T_n]$.)

To show this proposition, I've shown that $ X = \operatorname{D}_+(T_0) \subseteq \operatorname{Proj}k[T_0,\cdots T_n]/\overline{I}$, where $\overline{I} = (T_0^{\operatorname{deg}f_j}f_j(\frac{T_1}{T_0}, \cdots , \frac{T_n}{T_0}))_{j = 1, \cdots , m}$

(Since $\operatorname{D}_+(T_0) = \operatorname{Spec}(k[T_0,\cdots T_n]/\overline{I})_{(T_0)} = \operatorname{Spec}k[\frac{T_1}{T_0},\cdots \frac{T_n}{T_0}]/I' = X $, where $ I' = (f_j(\frac{T_1}{T_0}, \cdots , \frac{T_n}{T_0}))_{j=1, \cdots , m}$)

So now, it remains to show that

> $\operatorname{D}_+(T_0)$ is dense in $\operatorname{Proj}k[T_0,\cdots T_n]/\overline{I}$.

Please help.

Comment: Why not just replace your proj with the closure of $D_{+}(T_0)$ in the proj, thereby making density moot?

Comment: @Mohan Oh no, you are completely right. I didn't notice that. Thank you very much.